# Video postprocessing on iOS

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

Given a bunch of timestamped lines, is there a way to add draw said lines over an existing video at the specified times in the video?

I have an array of objects representing a user drawn picture at a specific time, and would like to draw this over the video at the attached time.

I had been looking at the `AVMutableVideoComposition`'s `animationTool` but have been struggling with constructing an animation out of the data I have.

Comment: This tutorial might help you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos